# Ddos an ip address with loic

Tags: java, ip, ip-address, ddos, denial-of-service

I am a student in ICT at the university. I am trying to understand DDOS/DOS.

I downloaded LOIC to DDOS myself and to check what it does.

I am at my parents place now, my girlfriend is at our home, when i try to dos my own network at home it just won't work, it only gives me huge ping spikes and barely any ping spikes to my home where my girlfriend is at... How is this not working? Am i using the wrong ip? I checked my home's IP on http://whatismyipaddress.com/. Btw I am only using one computer to ddos myself.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Most likely you are behind a router whose NAT will not let LOIC even through to your home PC... but an informatics student should know about that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about LOIC, which is not a programming tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LOIC change the method tab to UDP. Also try testing out the maximum amount of threads that your computer can handle. Hope this helps.